# iOS 9 Swift Adding pin and current location annotation

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, mapkit

Trying to add an annotation that displays the current location and a pin on the map, however both the current location, and the pin I want to add get added as a pin. If I change the line "view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "annotation")" to "view = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "annotation")" neither of the pins get added! 
Help!

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    //Try to dequeue an annotation like in the table view
    var view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("annotation")
    //If you can't dequeue an annotation create one, use the same identifier as above that way these annotations you create down here can be reused eventually.
    if view == nil {
        view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "annotation")
        view?.canShowCallout = true
    }else{
        return view
    }

    return view
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You are requesting 2 annotations from your mapView and want to treat them differently.  You need an if/else or switch statement in that function to say `if this is current location do this, else do this`.

Comment: I understand that, but what is the Annotation Initializer for Current Location?

Comment: You should check if the annotation is an `MKUserLocation` and return `nil` in that case so it shows the default annotation view

Comment: Fixed! Thanks a lot Dan